# PHP change password (old password does not match with the old password inside the database)

Tags: php, mysql, session, passwords

Here is my code

```
<?php
  include("connect.php");
  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();

  if($_SESSION['logged'] == true){

      if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 2){
          header("location:admin\home.php");
      }

      $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $id";

      $q = mysqli_query($con,$query);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
          $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];
      }

    if($user_id)
    {
        //user is logged in

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
          //check fields

          $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
          $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
          $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


          //check passwords
          if ($oldpassword == $oldpassworddb)
          {
             // check two new passwords
             if ($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword)
             {
                //success
                //change password in db
                $querychange = mysqli_query("
                UPDATE tbl_useraccounts SET password='$newpassword' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

                session_destroy();
                echo "Your password has been changed<br/>
                <a href='home.php'>Return</a>";

             }
             else
                 echo "New passwords doesnt match";


         }
         else
             echo "Old password doesnt match!";



    }
    else
    {

    echo"
    <form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
        Old Password: <input type='password' name='oldpassword'><p>
        New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br>
        Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Change Password'>
    </form>
    ";

      }
  }
  else 
      die("You must be logged in to change your password");

  }else{

      header("location:login.php");
  }
?>
```

I'm sorry I'm new to StackOverflow. When I type my old password inside the password bar, example is "123" wherein 123 is really the password stored in my database. But the always response when I click Change Password is "Old password does not match". 123 = 123 should be read as correct.

What is the error in my code?

Comment: You do _not_ want to use the unsafe `md5hash` algorithm to store passwords!

Comment: See the database and tell me what password did it store?

Comment: On top of what @arkascha has said, an md5 hash can be broken in seconds. What I recommend using is [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to hash your passwords.

Comment: Code does not lie, if you do `md5("something")` and compare it with `md5("something")` you always get that they're the same. If you don't then you're doing an `md5` of two different things. The question you should ask yourself is why are they different. The question I keep asking my self is why do people keep insisting on making their own login/user management systems when there's hundreds of solutions out there that work perfectly fine.

Comment: Also use parameterized queries, since your current method is extremely easy to do SQL injection on. For example you could us http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Since I'm new to PHP. I just knew that md5 hash is not recommended. Thank you all for your answers and help. I will now just apply what you all said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be picking wrong user as :

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // here you pick in $user_id
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $id"; // here you check with $id
```

so change to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $user_id";
```

Also `print_r($variable)` can be helpful for you.

Comment: I changed it but still => old password does not match. Is there any mistype error in my code? Or maybe the database connection

Comment: write following code after `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];`
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_id);
echo '</pre>';`
& let me know the result

Comment: It says 2. I'm sorry for the very late response. Hope to see your next reply here. Thanks

Comment: Now check on database. Does the user with user_id = 2 exists? and Is the  password encrypted or not. Also, you can use same previous technique of `print_r` to check what is the output upto that line. If you find missing output on particular line than you can be more specific where is your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $id";
```

To

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $user_id";
```

You have stored user id in the $user_id variable but using $id variable, which is not defined.

Comment: Changed but still not working. Is it my database now the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You used **$id** insted of **$user_id** in the where statment:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $id";

$q = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
    $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];
}
```

You can dump the value which is in the database like this:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_useraccounts where user_id = $id";

$q = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
            $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];
            var_dump($oldpassworddb);
        }
```

Check how many user's you have in the db. Dump your old password and compare it to the one you are providing. If it doesn't match, change the password in the db with the result of:

```
var_dump(md5('123'));
```

Then run your code again. At this point we can't be sure what is sitting in your db ;)

Comment: I changed it now but still password does not match

Comment: @JpTamayo Can you tell us what do you have in your db?